# MediaWiki: Using a template result as an internal wiki link parameter

Tags: templates, hyperlink, mediawiki

In this explanation, the following variables are used:

- A: Page address
- B: Page name
- C: Category Name
- D: Variable. Value is 'A'
- T: Template
- V: Variable

Using MediaWiki, the syntax for using a link is `[[C/A|B]]`. This creates a link to page A, which is inside category C, with text B. The syntax for using a template inside another template with a variable as an argument is `{{T|{{{V|#}}}}}` This produces the result of template T with variable V. Suppose this result is exactly A. Now, combining these approaches, I expect the code `[[C/{{T|{{{V|#}}}}}|B]]` to produce the same link as the link syntax example. However, the result is:

```
[[C/A|B]]
```

E.g. exactly the code that needs to be evaluated. Note how the template does get evaluated correctly, but the link is not parsed. It seems like I need to 'reverse' the priority some way.

Side note: My approach does work with just variables. E.g. if variable D were to hold the value A, the code `[[C/{{{D|#}}}|B]]` does produce the correct link. MediaWiki documentation is surprisingly sparse on the subject.

Hint: Wikipedia itself has a number of link templates that can be used as examples, however these form a complex interwoven web from which it is hard to interpret the correct notation for this particular case.

Questions:

1. How do I properly call a template inside of this context?
2. What about using the template result for other parts of the link,
   such as the text?
3. What if this is a linked image or other special link?

Other things:

Preferrably, the solution should involve the use of only a single template if this is possible. If a 'dummy' link template containing a simple [[{{{1}}}]] is required, is there a default MediaWiki template that can do this, reducing clutter?

Comment: "inside category" is incorrect

Comment: While indeed the fact that A is a subpage of C in the example does not change the fact that the template used won't produce a link but instead produces the link code, I included it for completeness, ergo, for all I know this might affect the correct solution.